# Error during exe file run however .py file is running well

Tags: python-2.7, pyinstaller

I've developed a code in python 2.7 using a vendor propitiatory library. The reason behind using python 2.7 is the require library is in python 2 environment. After executing the code from IDLE, it is running fine though the .exe file made from installer is giving error. can anyone help me out to troubleshoot the issue.

The environment used to create the exe file is as below:
Package              Version

---

enm-client-scripting 1.18.1
pip                  18.1
PyInstaller          3.5

While running the exe file it is giving error and the error producing in the lie where the below library is being imported.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ENM_GUI.py", line 8, in 
  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 395, in load_module

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ENM_GUI.py", line 8, in 
The above line is giving error and in this line actually importing the enmscripting library. Moved the importing option fro one line to another (obviously before executing the actual code) to reproduce the error and found the this perticular importing is causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use pyinstaller quite often, and while your post is somewhat ambigious, it sounds like your pyinstaller cannot find the module. Few things you can do,  based on pyinstaller documentation: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html

1) Extending module paths: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#extending-the-path

2) Listing hidden imports: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#listing-hidden-imports

3) Extending packages' path: https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/when-things-go-wrong.html#extending-a-package-s-path